# ui-grid pagination page forward button not disabled even with 0 record

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using `ui-grid` for my tables, with `externalpagination` and `externalfiltering` set to true. When the `$http` returns no record after searching, the `page-forward button` should be disabled, but it doesn't, which cause issues ahead.

Here's an image[image]

Here's the image of it, which shows the button still visible. Please help me out. Stuck with this for a while

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I can't do much without your code, but my best guess would be that you need to set the `allData, minRowsToShow` and `excessRows` properties when you get the data from the external pagination and/or external filter:

```
let pageSize = 20;
vm.gridOptions.allData = response.data;
vm.gridOptions.minRowsToShow = response.data.length < pageSize ? response.data.length : pageSize;
vm.gridOptions.excessRows = response.data.length;
```

I hope this helps